# What is Service-Now and how is it related to ITSM?

Tags: servicenow

I'm new to Service-Now, can anyone help me to find out what is ITSM and how Service-Now is related to it.

What is the best way to learn this tool so that it is easy to know and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Service-Now started out as an Cloud ITSM Tool, now it contains much more and you can also create custom application on the Platform. But I would suggest you check out there Wiki and Community which is actually pretty good.

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Get_Started

https://community.servicenow.com/welcome

ITSM is broad topic, it's about Incident, Change, Problem Management and a proper CMDB. You will find enough on the web. Like on Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book:IT_Service_Management